# Integral of secant - Where's the mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't find what's wrong in my attempt on finding the integral of $f(x)=\sec(x)$

$$\int \sec(x) \, dx = \int \frac{dx}{\cos(x)} = \int \frac{\cos(x) \, dx}{\cos^2(x)} = \int\frac{\cos(x)\,dx}{1-\sin^2(x)}$$
$$\sin(x) = u \\\\\\\\\\\ du = \cos(x) \, dx$$
$$\int \frac{du}{1-u^2}=\int \frac{A}{1+u} \, du + \int \frac{B}{1-u} \, du = \int\frac{A(1-u) B(1+u)}{1-u^2} \, du$$
$$ A=B=\frac{1}{2} $$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1+u} \, du + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1-u} \, du= \frac{1}{2}(\ln(1+\sin(x))+\ln(1-\sin(x))$$

Comment: Preceed $sec$, $sin$, $cos$ and $ln$ with a \ to get $\sec,\dots ,\ln$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral of $\dfrac{1}{1-u}$ is $-\ln(|1-u|)$. You left out the minus sign in front. (This comes in principle from the substitution $t=1-u$.)

**Remark:** Since differentiation is so easy, it is useful to scan a conjectured antiderivative for correctness. For example, that's the way I would integrate $\sin(1+3t)$. The answer is something like $\cos(1+3t)$. Differentiate. We get $-3\sin(1+3t)$, wrong. Easy fix, multiply by $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Oh, that was dumb! Thanks you very much!
While we are at it, any general ideas on how to go from my result to $\ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x))$ ?

Comment: $\ln(1+\sin(x))-\ln(1-\sin(x)=\ln(\frac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)})=\ln(\frac{(1+\sin(x))^{2}}{1-\sin^{2}(x)})=\ln(\frac{(1+\sin(x))^{2}}{\cos^{2}(x)})=2\ln(\frac{1+ \sin(x)}{\cos(x)})$